# using a variable in listen command siriproxy

Tags: ruby, siri

I am setting up a listen command to grab a string of words in my siriproxy project.

The string can be anything, so the easiest way is to make sure the string starts with a special word. I want to set that word in a variable. That way, I can give the user a way to change it.

Here is what I have:

```
listen_for /Elvis ([a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]*)/i do |event_name|
```

My command will begin with `Elvis`, and everything after it becomes the variable `event_name`.

What if I wanted `Elvis` to be a variable? I tried this with a big fail.

```
listen_for /#{myVar} ([a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]*)/i do |event_name|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listen_for /#{Regexp.escape myVar} ([a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]*)/i do |event_name|`

Comment: nope same result. it skips right by. I know my variable is pulling in from the config file right. But this solution doesnt catch it either.

Comment: putting # just makes it think it is a comment